# MongoDB - error during aggregation - Operation exceeded time limit

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

When I run the following lookup aggregation with little data it works fine, but when I run it with a lot of data (subTotals has 1,440,000 documents) it takes a long time and in the end it fails to run due to the following error:

> PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: operation exceeded time limit

I don't know how to fix this.

I have tried:

- Adding indexes
- Add { allowDiskUse: true }
- Increase the maxTimeMS

But nothing works. I don't know what I can do.

This is the pipeline of my aggregation :

```
[
   {
        $lookup: {
            from: "subItems",
            let: {
                products: "$products",
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $in: ["$idItem", "$$products"],
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            as: "subItems",
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Instead of `"$lookup"`'s `"let"`/`"pipeline"`, if you use `"localField": "products", "foreignField": "idItem"`, and have an index on `"idItem"` in the `"subItems"` collection, does the performance increase?  Also, do you really want this aggregation for every document in the base collection (`"subTotals"`?)?

Comment: Have you inspected the explainPlan to identify the bottleneck? Also, if your `subItems` collection is properly indexed, you might be able to workaround the issue by reversing the `$lookup` i.e. lookup from `subItems` to the source collection; but that will depends on the selectivity of your 2 collections.